# Not getting attached photo information using Foursquare PUSH API

Tags: api, push, photo, foursquare

I am using Foursquare PUSH API(Checkins from your users will be pushed to your app)..
I have set an url at my server where I am receiving PUSH response..However when someone attaches photo (with public visible option on) at time of check-in, I do not get that photo related info(URL, img name etc) as a part of response at my end..Please guide me how can I get attached photo info as well..I want to display that attached image on my site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point our push API only supports notifying you when a user checks in, which is actually separate from when a photo is added to a check-in, although it seems seamless. Photos are actually added to a check-in via a separate API call ([photos/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add)—you'll notice that there's no way to include a photo in [checkins/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) itself)

You need to make separate [check-in detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins) calls to see if a particular check-in has a photo associated with it

Comment: They have button in the app settings which lets push test check ins. When we use that button it does give us image data where as when we do real check in it does not. They should correct it otherwise its gonna confuse developers.

Comment: @octopi
As mentioned, we are making a seperate check-in detail call to see if a particular check-in has a photo associated with it.. However when we start parsing push response to get check-in id to make seperate check-in detail call, we do not receive associated photo details immediately even though photo is associated with it. but when we make check-in detail call sometimes later, we do get associated photo details
As you mentioned, "photos are actually added to a check-in via a separate API call".Is this a possible reason for not getting photo details immediately ? Please suggest solution